# Difference between user and app-only auth?

Tags: twitter

I've been read the Twitter docs but must be missing something.

User auth and app-only auth have different rate limits and capabilities, but I'm struggling to get a handle on use cases for each.

Is user auth just for "Sign in with Twitter" style apps, and so because you're acting on behalf of the user you can do more?

What is app only auth? I have generated a key manually for an account I have - because I created this manually without a user is that app only?

Very confused! Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE Dec, 2020:** Twitter recently launched API v2 and rate limits related to user or app auth are better described in [twitter official docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits).

This means you can access this API function with an **app auth** or a **user auth** tokens. In some requests you only can access with *user auth* token.

**App Auth number:** Is the highest number of requests your app can do in a 15min window, with 'app auth' token.

**User Auth number:** Is the highest number of requests your app can do in a 15min window, with 'user auth' token.

You need to know how your library/module is getting auth. [Source](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only)

Edit:
App Auth and User Auth are the two ways API [twitter can manage OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth). You can do with this python example using Twython module:

```py
from twython import Twython

# App Auth
tw_auth = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, oauth_version=2)
token = tw_auth.obtain_access_token()
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, access_token=token)
```

By other way, if you want to authenticate with User Tokens:

```py
from twython import Twython

# User Auth
tw_auth = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
token = tw_auth.get_authentication_tokens()
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, auth['oauth_token'],
          auth['oauth_token_secret'])
```

(...this last method [is a bit longer](http://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html#oauth-1-user-authentication), because with the authentication tokens you need to `.get_authorized_tokens(prompted_pin)` to make a new Twython method call. This is only an example to show you need 4 keys/tokens instead 2)

Now, if you make a request, the counter for your 15min window depends on how you are authenticated:

```py
# Now you are authenticated with *App Auth* or *User Auth*
# Limits will be 450 for AppAuth and 180 for UserAuth in 15min window
results = twitter.search(q='StackOverflow',result_type='recent', count='10')
```

These differences exists because not all API methods support application-only authentication. Some methods require a user context.

**Edit:**

> I could do with real world scenarios where you would use one over the other?

Of course! look this [chart about Twitter rate limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) and compare. Sometimes you can't make requests with appAuth-only, for example user related actions. Limits are different for each auth, if you want [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) maybe you prefer AppAuth, but if you want [GET lists/members](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/members) maybe you would prefer UserAuth, because it has some advantage with rate limits.

Comment: I think I need an example of both, if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: @Jon I hope my new explanation with examples could help you

Comment: Thanks @rutrus but I still have questions. I could do with real world scenarios where you would use one over the other?

Comment: @Jon I completed my answer with your question. If it solves your questions, please, mark my answer as `accepted`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that other answers focus on the "rate limit" mentioned in the question and do not clarify the two types of authentication about which the OP is confused. So this answer is for those who are still searching for this clarification and not finding much.

**First**, a general explanation of User Authentication vs. App Authentication:

- **User Authentication** authenticates a specific user. User authenticated requests to an API would most likely include requests
  for user specific data (but not always). Because the user has been
  authenticated with the API/server the API knows the functions to
  which the user has access and knows which user data to return from
  those functions. An example of this type of app would perhaps be a
  personal calendar app that tracked specific calendar events for the
  individual logged-in user.
- **App Authentication** authenticates the whole app, regardless of the user. "This method is typically for developers that need read-only
  access to public information" ([Twitter OAuth2 docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0)). An example
  of an app-only authenticated app would maybe be an app that
  translates from English to Spanish by connecting to an online
  English-Spanish dictionary API. Only the app needs to be
  authenticated since the users are not logged in and there is no user
  specific data. Of course this example falls apart if you added a user
  login and translation history or something similar but hopefully you
  get the point.

**Second**, now that you understand a little more about the two authentication types, you will probably be able to appreciate why there are considerable differences in the **rate limits** on each type. A user authentication would likely use far less API requests compared to the number of API requests for an app-only authentication. For app-only, the total API requests for a day or a month or whatever the time period would include the requests of *all* the anonymous users during that time period. Hence the differing API limits for each type.

Answer (score 0):

The difference:

User auth: how many request you can send on a specific user (it dosent have to be a logg user but any user you send a request to get data)

app auth: how many request you can send in total request you meid in 15 win that mean without depending on specific user.

Comment: Could you clailrify "send on a specific user"?

Comment: Let's say I am using a method called get followers (user id)
That mean I am sending a request for a specific user
If I will send another request using the "user id" again that mean the request will be counted for a specific user!

App auth count the number of request not depending on the user you send (user id)