# user auth vs app auth (Twitter API)

Tags: php, api, twitter

i'm new using this API (Twitter API) and have a little problem with those 2 terms, `user auth` and `app auth`, i'm using this API version: `https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php`, and noticed i have a limited use each day, i only found this thread `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462106/difference-between-user-and-app-only-auth` but wasn't very clear, are there some short example to see the difference between both?

Thank you.